# What's the difference between PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC and its absence?

Tags: linux, ptrace

According to the ptrace man page,

> If the PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC option is not in effect, all successful calls to execve(2) by the traced process will cause it to be sent a SIGTRAP signal, giving the parent a chance to gain control before the new program begins execution.

If the option *is* in effect,

> Stop the tracee at the next execve(2). A waitpid(2) by the tracer will return a status value such that `status>>8 == (SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_EVENT_EXEC<<8))`. If the execing thread is not a thread group leader, the thread ID is reset to thread group leader's ID before this stop. Since Linux 3.0, the former thread ID can be retrieved with PTRACE_GETEVENTMSG.

So if the option isn't set, the tracee gets SIGTRAP and stops so the tracer can gain control. If the option *is* set, the tracee gets SIGTRAP and stops. What's the difference (besides the part about threads at the end)?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is not on the tracee side, but on the tracer side.  Without the option, the tracer can not distinguish `PTRACE_EVENT` stop following `execve` and incoming `SIGTRAP`; it cannot use `PTRACE_GETEVENTMSG`; plus, the delivery method is different: if I'm not mistaken, without the option if `SIGTRAP` is already pending. it's not re-enqueued (as usual for non-realtime signals).

Answer (score 1):

I will provide a concrete example illustrating one difference.

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main() {
  pid_t child;
  int status = 0;
  child = fork();
  if(child == 0) {
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
    raise(SIGSTOP);
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
  } else {
    wait(&status);
    // ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, child, NULL, PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC);
    printf("%d\n", status >> 8);
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, NULL);
    wait(&status);
    printf("%d\n", status >> 8);
    printf("%d\n", (SIGTRAP | PTRACE_EVENT_EXEC << 8));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

We will get `19` (SIGSTOP) and `5` (SIGTRAP). After uncommenting the `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` line, we will get `19` and `1029` which is the same as `(SIGTRAP | PTRACE_EVENT_EXEC << 8)`.